# Dual boot Win10/ParrotOS - Can't stop booting to grub recovery after update

Tags: dual-boot, grub, parrotsec

Updated ParrotOS (dual booted with Win10) via `parrot-update` and landed in grub recovery after reboot (don't know why but that's another problem for another day).  All was working fine for ages up until last night.  Single drive with following partition table:

- nvme0n1p1 - EFI system
- nvme0n1p2 - Microsoft reserved
- nvme0n1p3 - Microsoft basic data
- nvme0n1p4 - Linux filesystem (/boot (ext4))
- nvme0n1p5 - Linux filesystem (/ (ext4))
- nvme0n1p6 - Linux swap (swap)

When booting the system goes to grub recovery.  A quick inspection:

`set`

- cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/kali
- prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
- root=hd0,gpt6

I believe /EFI/kali is from my initial attempt at loading kali ages ago but do not know how to clean it up.  However, I do the following to get grub to work:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt4)/grub
set boot=(hd0,gpt5)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt4)/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Once inside I have tried `sudo apt update` then `sudo update-grub` then `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1` all without error.  However, when I reboot it lands back in grub recovery.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I cannot get grub to boot from nvme0n1p4 (gpt4) permanently?  Should it be booting from nvme0n1p1 (gpt1) and thus should I reinstall Parrot without the /boot mount point?  Note that I have tried this but still land in grub recovery.  I don't care about re-installing Parrot from scratch but am trying not to wipe Win10 partitions at all.

Should also mention that I have also booted from live USB and tried mounting drives, updating grub from there still results in boot to grub recovery.

Appreciate any support.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Boot using a live USB/cd of ubuntu. Use boot-repair to fix the problem.